Python class method "missing 1 required positional argument"
I want to create a class method that will value from the class itself, but I can't use (self) as the parameter, because it is class method (cls). Is there a fix for this problem?
class DiscountProduct(Product):
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity, discount_percentage):
        super().__init__(name, price, quantity)
        self.disc = discount_percentage

    @classmethod
    def total_stock_value(cls):
        return sum(i.price*(self.disc/100)*i.quantity for i in cls.products)

DiscountProduct("Keyboard Mechanical Razer BlackWidow", 1500, 15, 100),
DiscountProduct("Monitor LG UltraGear 27GL850", 5000, 25, 50)

print(DiscountProduct.total_stock_value())

Output:
    print(DiscountProduct.total_stock_value())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: DiscountProduct.total_stock_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'

or:
print(DiscountProduct.total_stock_value(Product))

Output:
return sum(i.price*(self.disc/100)*i.quantity for i in cls.products)
                        ^^^^
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Though I could do something like this:
class DiscountProduct(Product):
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity, discount_percentage):
        super().__init__(name, price, quantity)
        self.disc = discount_percentage

    def total_stock_value(self):
        return sum(i.price*(self.disc/100)*i.quantity for i in Product.products)

a = DiscountProduct("Monitor LG UltraGear 27GL850", 5000, 25, 25)
DiscountProduct("Keyboard Mechanical Razer BlackWidow", 1500, 15, 100),
DiscountProduct("Monitor LG UltraGear 27GL850", 5000, 25, 25)

print(a.total_stock_value())

Output:
207750.0

Where is my fault?

Please give a [mre] - what is Product? MyClass.class_method() certainly works with a @classmethod as you show, cls is available, but self certainly won't be (maybe you meant i.disc?)

What is cls.products? You either neglected to update this class attribute in __init__, or you are assuming the class tracks its instances automatically. It does not, and it should not. At the very least, you should have separate classes for defining a product and defining a collection of products.

Also, you should never create an object simply for the side effect from creating it.

total_stock_value should be a standalone function that takes a list of DiscountProducts as an argument.
class DiscountProduct(Product):
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity, discount_percentage):
        super().__init__(name, price, quantity)
        self.disc = discount_percentage

def total_stock_value(products: list[DiscountProduct]):
    return sum(i.price*(self.disc/100)*i.quantity for i in products)

ps = [
    DiscountProduct("Keyboard Mechanical Razer BlackWidow", 1500, 15, 100),
    DiscountProduct("Monitor LG UltraGear 27GL850", 5000, 25, 50)
]

print(total_stock_value(ps))

One thing you could add to DiscountProduct is a method that computes the value of that product and can be used by total_stock_value:
class DiscountProduct(Product):
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity, discount_percentage):
        super().__init__(name, price, quantity)
        self.disc = discount_percentage

    def value(self):
        return self.price * (self.disc / 100) * self.quantity


def total_stock_value(products: list[DiscountProduct]):
        return sum(i.value() for i in products)

Whether you want to define a second class whose instances represent sets of discount products (and thus could have total_stock_value as an instance method) is up to you.

you can solve this proplem so:
class DiscountProduct(Product):
    products = []
     
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity, discount_percentage):
        super().__init__(name, price, quantity)
        self.disc = discount_percentage
        DiscountProduct.products.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def total_stock_value(cls):
        return sum(i.price*(i.disc/100)*i.quantity for i in cls.products)

DiscountProduct.total_stock_value(DiscountProduct)

or
class DiscountProduct(Product):
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity, discount_percentage):
        super().__init__(name, price, quantity)
        self.disc = discount_percentage

    @classmethod
    def total_stock_value(cls):
        return sum(i.price*(i.disc/100)*i.quantity for i in cls.products if isinstance(i, DiscountProduct))

DiscountProduct.total_stock_value(Product)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
